# SDK Manager Not showing required packages to Install

Tags: android, sdk

I downloaded the Android SDK Manager latest version and installed(Windows 32bit),then i open SDK manager to install all other packages requiredt to develop an app,It is shows nothing other than SDK tools which are installed with SDK Manager.Can any help to install all other packages??
Note:Also as an Administrator,No Firewall and also no Antivirus.(Intranet connection)

Comment: Can you plz,tell me how to set proxy setting and where to find so...and all ??

Comment: @FilmCreator First Update ADT Plugin and then try.

Comment: As far as I can remember, this uses the global system proxy setting. In Windows (only OS I've ever used a proxy with), it's in Internet Settings which you can find from the control panel or Internet Explorer. Just Google "android sdk proxy" to get help, if this is your issue.

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya Yes already i have ADt Latest Plugin

Comment: @FilmCreator Are you using which version of ADT Plugin?

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya Revision 20.0.3

Comment: I could mnager till all other tools for an application by copying from another computer,But now i have problem with Android Support Libraries i Cant find them by SDK manger and also not with Eclipse,when i press install/upgrade button happens nothing.But error for proceeding next step??

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, you can set it in your SDK Manager by going to tools/options.
But for some reason, if you start SDK Manager from Eclipse you will not find "options" under tools menu so you have to start SDK Manager from start menu or from shortcut.

Comment: I finally solve my problem with SDK Manager by changing Proxy Settins,Thankx to every one for helping me.

Comment: I only see `Manage Add-on Site` under Tools menu

Comment: When you start SDK Manager from Eclipse or from start menu?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my problem with SDK Manager by changing Proxy Settins,Thankx to every one for helping me.